# Can any type of bobbin be used as loading coil for antenna?

Tags: resistors, antenna, coil

The winded types of bobbin can be used as loading coil for antennas. There are also resistor-like ones. These are in comparison to other long bobbin variants, much smaller.
I will use an 8 Mhz radio transmission antenna. This is approximately 17.2 cm long and has a diameter for about 0.6 mm. I calculated the loading coil, that should be fixed on it for a shortened antenna. The loading coil should be 220.70 micro-Henry.
When I would to try to wind that much cable that would make 220 micro-Henry, it would cost a lot of time and the result may be incorrect.
Is it not better to make use of prepared resistor-like bobbin with the same effect on my antenna?

Comment: I think yes. But are there coils of that value in the market? And why $220uH$ would cost a lot of time? I don't think so, try to estimate thee number of turns [use these formulas](http://smirc.stanford.edu/papers/JSSC99OCT-mohan.pdf)

Comment: I bought lastly a 220 micro-Henry resistor-like bobbin. I will solder all the stuff together and see then, if it will work. I asked this question here to ensure myself, maybe it has a chance.

Comment: So this question just asks for a 'cheer on'?

Comment: No, but i am interested in wireless radio communications and i could not find any references about these bobbins.

Comment: Publish a paper then

Comment: Nice to meet you.

Comment: @dude that's probably because you're searching for "bobbins", and that isn't the relevant term. A bobbin is just the mechanical thing that (sometimes, but not even most of the time) holds the coil.

Comment: The small coil will be more lossey than the big coil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loading coil inductance value tallies with that obtained using [M0UKD's Loaded Quarter Wave Antenna Inductance Calculator](https://m0ukd.com/calculators/loaded-quarter-wave-antenna-inductance-calculator/).

Any 220 μH standard inductor, with either axial or radial leads, may be used.

[image]